# Where is EEPROM in Pi4?

Tags: pi-4, pi4-eeprom

I want to know the location of Pi4's EEPROM.
Is it in BCM 2711? or in memory chip? or as an individual module in board? I looked for many reference books（BCM2711 ARM Peripherals、Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4...），however，I couldn't find the answer. If you know where it is or references probably recording where it is，Please let me know.

thx.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md) answer your question? also if you are looking to update it you can visit [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom).

Comment: Thanks for your help，but these references can't solve my question. Anyway, thanks again! best wishes.

Answer (score 3):

I searched Datasheets of Processor and RAM and other components of RPI4 but couldn't found where it was then I stumbled upon the mentioned above link in a comment that RPI 4 has an SPI-EEPROM so I looked regarding that and found this question where the asker has an issue with boot loading. He mentioned where is EEPROM and also tested it with an Oscilloscope for any ERROR.

This was said by him:

**I see two chips near the AV jack that look like two SPI EEPROMs. I can try to hook up the oscilloscope there to see if the ROM is trying to load the EEPROM and what's there. Which one of the two is the bootloader EEPROM? (I assume the one labeled 4H916 064838)**

And Here's the Link:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=253776

Please go through the conversation the RPI moderator/engineer didn't say it is wrong.

Comment: I do thank you so much. Probably two chips near AV jack are EEPROM.

Comment: @jiaming You are welcome. If you find my answer correct please tick it so the next person does not have to work hard.

Answer (score 0):

In a short, as can be seen in the picture, two chips near AV jack probably are EEPROM.
[image: 在这里插入图片描述]